# JavaScript on Google's homepage?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what the JavaScript on Google's homepage does?

For such a simple homepage, there's a lot of code there! It's obfuscated and really quite onerous. I don't want to spend ages looking at it just to find it's doing something mundane.

Just thought that someone else may have looked at it already. Interested to know...

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: Well, there's a lot of things: Sign in, search, change background, integrate Google Plus etc.. (Don't forget the search page: the search page isn't an entirely different page on its own)

Comment: Probably the auto-complete stuff..

Comment: *"I don't want to spend ages looking at it just to find it's doing something mundane."* - I have some bad news for you about most software development...

Comment: I agree. "For such a simple homepage..." is untrue. It looks simple, but it is powerful with all that autocomplete, autosearch, and so on, stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly your AJAX requests for autocomplete. Also, to make the search `div` box look like a text field. (It isn't a text field. Try pausing JS from the console, you'll see the cursor stop blinking.) Moreover, a lot of styling of it's UI elements.

Comment: Of course...autocomplete...I've been scrolling through the source, not thinking to actually type into it and think about what happens. I probably ought to be less suspicious :-) Thanks for your responses. Stackoverflow never ceases to amaze me. By far the best forum. I think answers were coming in in 60 seconds.